# rendered entity field markup on drupal 8 install

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Uncaught Error: Quick Edit could not associate the rendered entity field markup (with [data-quickedit-field-id="node/2/field_header/en/full"]) with the corresponding rendered entity markup: no parent DOM node found with [data-quickedit-entity-id="node/2"]. This is typically caused by the theme's template for this entity type forgetting to print the attributes.

This is the error I am getting. The pages are loading fine but it is throwing that error. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

A template somewhere is not printing the `{{ attributes }}` so a html element does not have an attribute that quick edit is trying to attach to.
It is not really a big deal, it just means quick edit will not function for that part of the page. Anonymous users should not have the permission to use quick edit, so they should not be affected.
You can either disable the quick edit module of find and fix the template that is not outputting the `{{ attributes }}`.
More info at: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2978799

Answer (score 0):

A dirty workaround if @2pha's answer doesn't work. Like the `attributes` somehow doesn't include `data-quickedit-entity-id` tag.

```
<div data-quickedit-entity-id="media/{{ media.id() }}" {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {% if content %}
    {{ content }}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```